# button click function not working

Tags: java, android, xml

I was trying to make button click and go to next activity but my code is not working. My java and xml code is here.

```
case R.id.menu_legalnotes:
       startActivity(new Intent(this, LegalNoticeActivity.class));
        return true;


    <Button
    android:id="@+id/menu_legalnotes"
    android:title="@string/legalnotes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/floors_fragment"
    android:text="Legal Notice" />
```

Comment: Can you paste more code? we do not know where is your "case R.id.menu_legalnotes:" written. If it's in a listener or a new method of the activity...

Comment: Also say if there is an error or just nothing happens

Comment: need to ensure that you have set the onClickListener too

Comment: nothing happen @Fenix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's the solution:**

**1)**
On your onCreate(){
.
.
.

```
public class TestClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menu_legalnotes);
        //If you have more buttons,
        Button secondButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.secondButtonID);
        //Register more buttons if you have.

    }
```

**2)**
On your **onClick(View v) :**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.menu_legalnotes:

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Your_SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;


            case R.id.secondButtonID:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Your_AnotherActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
         //You can add more cases here depending on what you want to achieve.

            default:
                break;
            }

    }
```

Should work now.. Enjoyy ..:)

Comment: Your code was worked but If I want to add more than one button than?

Comment: If you have more buttons, just add more cases to it. For example, I am editing my answer. Check it in 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

did you: findViewById(R.id.menu_legalnotes).setOnClickListener(this); ??

Answer (score 0):

In your activity get id for the button

In onCreate method declare as follows:

```
Button menuLegalNotes = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menu_legalnotes);

menuLegalNotes.setOnClickListner(new View.onClickListener){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
});
}
```